# Two question about RBJ Peak filter

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, bandwidth, c++, biquad

I'm new into DSP and Filters in general. Its the first step ahead I do from learning and using a 1-pole IIR basic Low Pass Filter.

I'm about to implement for my VST audio application (using C++ and IPlug Framework) a [RBJ's Peak filter](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/).

By steps (from that document), the formula that I'll use within my Process() function will be `y[n]`, thus (as code):

```
inline double Process(double input) {
    mBuffer += (b0/a0)*x[n] + (b1/a0)*x[n-1] + (b2/a0)*x[n-2] - (a1/a0)*y[n-1] - (a2/a0)*y[n-2];
    return mBuffer;
}
```

Since I'll use peakingEQ, I need to calculate these coefficients:

```
b0 =   1 + alpha*A
b1 =  -2*cos(w0)
b2 =   1 - alpha*A
a0 =   1 + alpha/A
a1 =  -2*cos(w0)
a2 =   1 - alpha/A
```

which all depends by `user defined parameters` and `intermediate variables`.

My questions are:

1. What's the difference between using Q (thus `sin(w0)/(2*Q)`) or BW  (thus `sin(w0)*sinh( ln(2)/2 * BW * w0/sin(w0))`) on calculating alpha? Isn't Bandwidth = Q when reasoing as Peak filter?
2. What's the meaning of `H(s)` function (which is `(s^2 + s*(A/Q) + 1) / (s^2 + s/(A*Q) + 1)` for the peaking filter)? I don't see where to "insert" it in the formulas.

I hope you can help me to undestand these two dubts.

Comment: uhm, *"Bandwidth"* cannot equal *"Q"* everywhere because they are monotonic decreasing functions of each other.  if you keep the definition between bandwidth (in octaves) and Q that you get with the -3 dB bandedges of the BPF, then $$ \frac1Q = 2 \sinh \left( \frac{\ln(2)}{2} BW \right) $$ is the relationship between the two. but there is a difference in definition of the bandedges in the Cookbook BPF and Peaking filter. (and the Q in the peaking is not the same as the EE definition of Q).

Comment: Oh... wow, you are RBJ :) Nice to talk with the genius himself. Big up for your intensive work, shared free for everyone! I think human being deserve more people like you. Well, I'm not a proper matematician, thus I didn't totally get what you mean. Usually on plugin when I switch between lowpass or peak, it keeps the same q (or bandwidth) param. At this point I think only the name remain the same, internally the coefficients change. So in my case (peak filter) I calculate alpha using the bandwidth formula right?

Comment: when Q gets higher, then BW gets skinnier.  one number goes up when the other goes down.  so they can't be the same thing, but they are **about** the same thing.  it's like *sample rate* vs. *sampling period*.  one goes up when the other goes down.  but they are referring to the same thing.  they are not two independent quantities.  Think of Q and BW as being two different sets of tick marks going around the same knob. (and my email is readily visible. i'm easy to get a hold of, but i am not always quick to respond.)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I see. The fact is: on your code, you write "case Q" and "case BW", which means two different alphas. Since I'll use peaking filter, which alpha should I use? The one using Q (`sin(w0)/(2*Q)`) or the one using BW (`sin(w0)*sinh( ln(2)/2 * BW * w0/sin(w0))`)? I need only one alpha right?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson; in this code for example: http://www.musicdsp.org/showone.php?id=128 . When should I pass `q_is_bandwidth` as true? Only for peaking?

Comment: no, you can meaningfully specify bandwidth for BPF and notch filters (in addition to peakingEQ).  and if you're an audio or music person, you likely specify bandwidth in octaves and that is how it is specified in the cookbook.  and for the BPF and notch, the -3 dB points are the bandedges.  but with the peakingEQ, it's at the half dB points from the peak dB (that changes the meaning of Q a little bit).

Comment: also, it's the same `alpha`.  there is only one `alpha`.  `Q` and `BW` are two different ways of specifying the same `alpha`.

Comment: recap: 1) if I use the filter as BPF, Notch or Peaking, q_is_bandwidth = true. 2) When I use BPF or North, Bandwidth value (which I pass as Q in that code) must be between 0 and -3.0 (I pass it the linear value I guess, so between 1 and 0.7079457843841379), else (if peaking) I pass a Q in the range between Min peak db + max peak db / 2 (linear again)?

Comment: I think I'll open a KVR thread, so I can make more clearity on this (I'm too much confused). Maybe you will see it there ;)

Comment: no, your recap is not correct.  it is also perfectly meaningful to specify a BPF, notch, and PeakingEQ with $Q$.  with BPF and notch, the Q is the same as the electrical engineering definition of Q.  but with the PeakingEQ, then the Q that you specify is $10^{-dBgain/40}$ times the electrical engineering definition of Q.  we fudged the definition a little so that a cut looks just like a boost (except upside-down) with the same $f_0$, same $|dBgain|$, and same $Q$ or $BW$.

Comment: It starts to make more sense. step by step... so if I use Q as EE, I'll use the alpha formula described as "case Q" (first alpha formula), else if I use Q as BW in octave I use the second alpha formula, described as "case BW". Correct till here?

Comment: yes, but don't call the bandwidth Q.  call it BW.  they are the same knob, but the tick marks on the knob are different.  Q gets larger as BW gets smaller.

Comment: and, for shelving filters, there is another option in lieu of Q.  and that is the Shelf Slope S.  if S=1, then the shelf slope is monotonic increasing or monotonic decreasing (i.e. no little bumps or lips).

Comment: Ok. Second step: which values should I set to Q, BW and S? Since I need to use EE/Octaves/monotonic values (and my knob goes from 0.01 to 1.0 within my audio plugin), it should be scaled accordly right? A simple LinearToDecibel function for EQ/BW? And S remains 0.01 to 1.0?

Comment: 0.01 seems awful small for anything.  1 is a good starting value for any of these.

Comment: The things starts to be clear, step by step :) I've found this, which has helped a lot: http://www.rane.com/note170.html . Let say I specify a BW of 2.00 (from my audio plugin's knob) for a BPF (or Notch) filter; it means 2 octaves wide for the band range of frequencies situated at -3db from the fc (i.e. the delta between f1 and f2, which are at -3db, is 2 octaves). This is the same of using a Q value 0.667 (even if its meaningless use Q) for a BFP, Notch or Peaking filters. For a Peaking filter, BW is the delta between f1 and f2 which are situated at dbGain/2 (instead of -3db) from fc. Right?

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson : I think I miss something. If I try to use Q or BW with the values above, they seems not interchangeable (alpha isnt the same) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbbc4e9d66acf27b Different conversion between BW and Q?

Comment: of course they are not the same.  they are **related**.  even *tightly* related.  but they are not the same.  the relationship between $Q$ and $BW$ in octaves for an **analog** BPF (or notch) is: $$ \frac{1}{Q} \ = \ 2 \ \sinh \left( \frac{\ln(2)}{2} BW \right) $$  for a digital filter (like the cookbook), the bandwidth gets scrunched a bit by the *frequency warping* effect of the bilinear transform and the approximate relationship is $$ \frac{1}{Q} \ = \ 2 \ \sinh \left( \frac{\ln(2)}{2} BW \frac{2 \pi f_0/F_s}{\sin(2 \pi f_0/F_s)} \right) $$

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson : ah ok perfect, so its normal they are slighly differents. Are my last recap correct so? Nice. So, after learning this... the Q Ill provide for a low pass filter (where there is no dbGain) refers to what? f1 and f2?

Comment: **what** is *"slightly different"*???  $Q$ and $BW$?  No, one goes up while the other goes down.  that's not the same as "slightly different".  they can differ by a great amount in the extremes.

Comment: second-order LPF and HPF can have resonance, too, if the poles are complex conjugate, which happens when $Q>\frac12$.  this resonance will be coupled to how sharp the LPF or HPF cutoff is.

Comment: alpha is slightly different. Of course BW and Q are different. As you said, "alpha is one" (even if slightly different using two-related BW and Q, 0.667 and 2.0)

Comment: $\alpha$ is slightly different from **what**??  some other $\alpha$?

Comment: If I calcolate it using Q 0.667 (case Q) or BW 2.0 (case BW), the alphas I got are slightly different (even if BW=2.0 = Q=0.667 following http://www.rane.com/note170.html)

Comment: try a very high sample rate and the equation i stated above (which is used in the cookbook) will be virtually compatible with the Rane document.  And you need to be more precise with your mathematical expression.  just above you are saying that "2.0 = ... = 0.667".  two different numbers are not equal to each other.

Comment: :) well I'm not discuting your brillant work. "I am" a coder, not a matematician, of course I trust your formula. I just need to understand how to use them. I thought (without trying them as audio) that the relationship between alpha calculated with Q or BW were exactly the same. its not, but tight (slight). thats enough for me ;) I guess it wont be noticeable on listening the filtered audio ;)

Comment: well, the cookbook was written in a way that people can apply the "recipes" without really knowing how the math works.  (and i put in a brief explanation of sorta how the math works.)  $Q$ an $BW$ are about the very same knob.  but the tick marks for the knob are different.  as you turn the knob clockwise, one of those parameters **in**crease and the other parameter **de**creases.

Comment: yes, but this is what I'm actually asking right now :) if they come from the same knob, I must be able to switch between Q and BW when I want. So there must be a relationship between Q and BW values I'll provide to your algo. Rane relationship seems concrete, but it will never be exactly the same. Similar (and probably un-noticeable, even at low audio sample rate of 44100), but not the same. Am I correct?

Comment: Or maybe there are some Q - BW relation (different of Rane document) which makes the switch between these two ways of operate around the band cut the same? I dont know, just asking :)

Comment: i am giving up.  all i can do is repeat what i wrote before.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48797/discussion-on-question-by-paizza-two-question-about-rbj-peak-filter).

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe this thread helps you in this Q - [Prewarping both resonant frequency $f_0$ and bandwidth (or $Q$) when using bilinear transform](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32196/prewarping-both-resonant-frequency-f-0-and-bandwidth-or-q-when-using-bilin)
2. H(s) is the s-plane transfer function

   Analog prototype of RBJ peak filter (Octave):

> ```
> K  = 10^(gain/40);
> w0 = 2*pi*fc;
> % H(s) = (s^2 + (K w0/Q)*s + w0^2) / (s^2 + w0 s/(K*Q) + w0^2)
> BC = [1 K*w0/Q w0^2];
> AC = [1 w0/(K*Q) w0^2];
> ```